# Difference between Spring Cloud Vault and Spring Cloud Config with Vault backend

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-vault-config

What is the difference between the followings?

- Spring Cloud Vault - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/
- Spring Cloud Config Server with Vault backend - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR4/#_spring_cloud_config_server

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring Cloud Vault is more lightweight because it does not require to run a java server (Spring Cloud Config Server) as a frontend for Vault, your Spring Boot app connects directly to Vault.

I have a small demo: https://github.com/gmarziou/demo-spring-cloud-vault

Comment: More specific: Spring Cloud Vault Config provides client-side support for externalized configuration by using Vault directly from the client. Spring Cloud Config Server is a configuration server with pluggable backends. You require a client component to access Spring Cloud Config Server to use the config data in your application.

Comment: Why Spring Cloud Vault doesn't require to run a java server? Probably Spring Cloud Vault runs tomcat

Comment: Because Spring Cloud Vault is a *client* library that connects to Vault REST API.

Comment: I am trying to use spring cloud vault config with azure authentication to connect to vault on AKS. having trouble as it seems the config itself is not read correctly : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69010328/spring-cloud-config-vault-with-azure-authentication  . I ahve asked a question here. Please help.

Comment: See also https://spring.io/projects/spring-vault, which is perhaps lighter weight, still.

Comment: Hello, those are very clear answers, many thanks. Is it possible to have an explanation for Spring Vault versus Spring Cloud Vault please? (not Spring Cloud Vault vs Spring Cloud Config Server with Vault backend)